# github: access denied after changing user.name globally

Tags: git, github

I took over a Mac OSX computer that previously had another person's github `user.email` and `user.name` cached. In order to access my own github repos, I changed the cached github user.email and user.name to mine. However, I still get denied to access (push) my repos on github. So I was wondering what I should do in order to push commits to my repos.

This is what I did to change the global github credentials on the computer:

```
git config --global user.name new_user_name
gitconfig --global user.email myemail@example.com
```

I checked the `.git/config` file in one of my cloned repos, and it uses the `https` URL, which is what I wish to keep using (not `ssh`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `.git-credentials` file in your `$HOME` you should completly delete it (it will be rebuilt by asking you your credentials once for each user/website).

Then you should have a look at your `$HOME/.gitconfig` and double-check if you have something like:

```
[user]
|   name = new_user_name
|   email = myemail@example.com
```

If you did that and still have the issue, try to update one of your repo's URL adding your raw username like `https://USERNAME@github.com/...` and try to push again. This is probably the best solution but forces you to update all your local repos config.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very helpful to me for solving the problem. I do not have .git-credentials in my $HOME, however, I do have .gitconfig there. So after I deleted .gitconfig, I can push to my repo on github. Thanks again!